# Facebook Connect from public applications

Tags: facebook, api, rest, web-applications

I'm building a RESTful API and I would like to allow users to sign-in or sign-up through Facebook.

My trouble is the following:

- if the Facebook Connect is performed *client-side*, I think I must add inside a SDK the APP_ID and the APP_SECRET, which is not good for security.
- if the Facebook Connect is performed *server-side*, the user experience can be worse when he is not logged in to Facebook (on his iPhone for instance).

So I don't really know how to do... By the way, am I right?

Is there a perfect method to handle a basic Facebook Connect for mobile applications?

Comment: Native application? or Mobile Web?

Comment: Both: native for Android and iPhone, and web mobile for HTML5 browser. With a same API.

Answer (score 0):

Use the appropriate SDK for each platform, until you get the `access_token`. Pass that access_token via HTTP SSL to an API call of yours like `facebook_login`.

On the API side, make a server-side call to the Graph API to get the facebook `user_id`. Match that user_id to a record in your database, and you know what user you're dealing with!

Now you're in a place where you can handle this like any other API login situation. Pass them a token or something for future API calls, or however you're choosing to authenticate it.